# Is the meta site supposed to support html?

Tags: discussion

This **link** should be an `a` html tag with `href"http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/"` but the site doesn't seem to be making it into a link.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We don't support html directly, we use markdown.  We've added a pretty extensive help section to our markdown editor - click the question mark and you will find a very precise instructions on how to use all of the features including links in our markdown editor.

There is also a toolbar when writing a post that should give quick links to frequently used formatting.

Answer (score 1):

You left out the `=` between `href` and the quoted URL. It works thus:

> This **[link](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/)** should be an `a` HTML tag with `href="https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/"` and the site seems to be making it into a link.

You had:

> This **https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/">link** should be an `a` html tag with `href"https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/"` but the site doesn't seem to be making it into a link.

Comment: While this is correct, this much is implied to anyone who knows even an modicum of HTML. This answer can be translated to **YOU'RE DOING IT WRONG!!!!!!**

Comment: @neilfein, well, yes, except that my answer was more informative than "you're doing it wrong": it explained *how* Yoel was doing it wrong, and what the right way is. Seems like a good answer to me....

Comment: Just saying, you can do the same thing with a simple edit or a comment. Dude, you're doing it wrong. :D